# How to make a combination of strings in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, combinations

I need to make a combinaion of Stings "a" "b" "c" "d".
I've tried putting them in a list then parsing a foreach methord through them, but to no avail.

What else can I do?

Comment: You mean to concatenate them ?

Comment: what do you mean by "combination"?

Comment: What do you mean to make a combination?

Comment: I want to get a program that outputs something like "abcd" "abdc" "acdb" "dacb" ect ect ect...

Comment: It seems that what you are looking for is actually permutations, not combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you the logic.

Create a `List<String>` and then go on adding each string to it.

```
List<String> s = new List<String>();  

s.add("a");
s.add("b");
s.add("c");
s.add("d");
```

Once you added all the strings, then generate a random number between minimum and maximum index like this :

```
private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
Random random = new Random();
return random.Next(min, max); 
}
```

Then, while printing each string in the loop over the List with this number, **be sure** to check that the same random number is not repeated for the nex iteration.

Comment: How would I add strings to the list string?

Comment: List<String> is a generic type, it will allow only strings to be added, no other object,

Answer (score 3):

Having the strings in an array you can use the function below to print all permutations so it outputs: abcd, abdc, adbc, etc.

Recursive permutation (from MSDN):

```
public static void Permute(string[] strings, int start, int finish)
  {
    if (start == finish)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i <= finish; ++i)
      {
        Console.Write(strings[i] + " " );
      }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
    else
    {
      for (int i = start; i <= finish; ++i)
      {
        string temp = strings[start];
        strings[start] = strings[i];
        strings[i] = temp;

        Permute(strings, start+1, finish);

        temp = strings[start];
        strings[start] = strings[i];
        strings[i] = temp;
      }
    }

  }  // Permute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Will a list do you?

```
List<String>myStrings = new List<String>();

myStrings.Add("a");
...
myStrings.Add("d");
```

You should be able to loop through that

Answer (score 0):

if you have a set number of strings you could use

```
var s = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", stringA, stringB, stringC, stringD);
```

otherwise a for/foreach loop would be the way forward,

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var strings = new List<string>();

// Add strings to list

for (var i = 0; i < strings.Count; i++)
{
    sb.Append(strings[i]);
}

var s = sb.ToString();
```

I wouldn't use string + string + string style concatenation as this is bad practice due to the way strings work in memory.

EDIT: I haven't tested the code it was written in the browser! let me know if you have any issues.

Just seen the comments above, the code I have posted will always output the strings in the same order so may not be what you want.

HTH

OneShot

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String>stringList = new List<String>();

stringList.Add("a");
stringList.Add("b");
...
...

foreach(string item in stringList)
 {
   string text=item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example does all the combinations (proper):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new [] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
        foreach (var combi in Enumerable.Repeat(list, list.Length).CartesianProduct())
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", combi));
    }

    static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) 
    { 
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }; 
        return sequences.Aggregate( 
                emptyProduct, 
                (accumulator, sequence) =>  
                from accseq in accumulator  
                from item in sequence  
                select accseq.Concat(new[] {item}));                
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a a a a
a a a b
a a a c
a a a d
a a b a
a a b b
a a b c
a a b d
a a c a
a a c b
....
d d b c
d d b d
d d c a
d d c b
d d c c
d d c d
d d d a
d d d b
d d d c
d d d d
```

If you needed permutations, you can drop-in an algorithm from

1. [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/branches/EvenMoreLINQ/MoreLinq/Permutations.cs)
2. CodeProject http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx