# How to get all combinations of a set of sets?

Tags: algorithm, set, combinatorics

I have a set of sets of strings.

I need to find every possible combination of strings.

Any ideas of the best way to go about this?

The language is C#, but I'm not looking for a concrete implementation, just a general approach to the problem.

Comment: Look into [power sets](http://sevko.io/articles/power-set-algorithms/).

Comment: Every combination as in one string from each set or every combination as in any number of strings from any number of sets? Please post an example.

Comment: As in any number of strings from any number of sets.

Comment: Thanks Henrik - this seems to be what I was looking for ;-)

Comment: @ThomasCook: No problem. Perhaps take a look at Guava's [PowerSet](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Sets.java#L1579) class.

Answer (score 1):

Put string into Listn and then create method that will generate random combination of your elements. Something like in:

[How to make a combination of strings in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276636/how-to-make-a-combination-of-strings-in-c)

EDIT:
Merge all Lists of string List into one long List of string.

```
    List<List<String>> sets = new List<List<String>>();
    List<String> allProducts = new List<String>();
    List<String> set1 = new List<String>() { "one", "two", "three" };
    List<String> set2 = new List<String>() { "111", "222", "333" };

    sets.Add(set1);
    sets.Add(set2);

    foreach (var set in sets)
    {
        allProducts.AddRange(set);
    }
```

Then perform operation on allProducts like in entry from above.

Comment: Yes but I'm dealing with a set of sets, something like this:

List<List<string>>

And  I need to find all combinations

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Example:

    `var toCombine= new List<List<string>>
    {
     new List<string>() { "ABC", "DEF" },
     new List<string>() { "39", "21" },
     new List<string>() { "Foo", "Bar" }
    };

    List<string> GetAllCombinations(List<List<string>> of)
    {
        // Return a set of strings where each string in the set is a combination of the input set of sets such that all possible combinations are returned...
    }`

Comment: I'm not sure how to format the code in a comment so it's all inline, sorry

Comment: Ok so you can use code I use above to create one list of strings and then apply logic from How to make a combination of strings in C#?